# PowerBI Count Query on multiple columns with filters

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to get counts of first_name and last_name. I want to then make a bar graph of the counts. I can accomplish this much by doing a power query with it grouped by first_name and last_name. But this eliminates the grade and year columns. Is there anyway to get the counts while still being able to filter on the year and grade columns?

Comment: it's task for DAX, not PQ (of course, you may do it in PQ too, but you shouldn't)

Comment: Sample output would help understand your actual requirenent.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using DAX measured for that. I'm guessing you want to count distinct values:

`First Names = DISTINCTCOUNT(Table[first_name])`

`Last Names = DISTINCTCOUNT(Table[last_name])`

Put these measures in a visual and you're done.

Comment: I should have been more specific i need to group columns together then count rows. I'm going to try using dax courtrows with groupby and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, can you update your question to show the expected result? I'm not sure I understand now. What do you mean group columns together? You want to join the columns and count full names? Or something else?